# How to QuerySelect using a recursive json object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I'm building a webscraper.  I have a json object of selectors that I need to iterate through so that I can grab each value on the page and capture the data.

How would I go about creating a lodash function that would walk each property recursively and execute a standard function to get the element inner text value based on the selector?

```
let startingJson = {

    address:"tbody > tr > td:nth-of-type(4) > p",
    comps: [{
        address: "tbody > tr:nth-of-type(1) > td:nth-of-type(1) > p",
        link: "tbody > tr:nth-of-type(1) > td:nth-of-type(1) > p > a",
        dateLastSold: "tbody > tr:nth-of-type(1) > td:nth-of-type(2) > p",
        value: "tbody > tr:nth-of-type(1) > td:nth-of-type(3) > p"
    },
    {
        address: "tbody > tr:nth-of-type(2) > td:nth-of-type(1) > p",
        link: "tbody > tr:nth-of-type(2) > td:nth-of-type(1) > p > a",
        dateLastSold: "tbody > tr:nth-of-type(2) > td:nth-of-type(2) > p",
        value: "tbody > tr:nth-of-type(2) > td:nth-of-type(3) > p"
    }]
}


let finalJsonExample = {

    address:"123 Main Street",
    comps: [{
        address: "234 Main Street",
        link: "abc.com",
        dateLastSold: "10/20/19",
        value: "100000"
    },
    {
        address: "345 Main Street",
        link: "def.com",
        dateLastSold: "10/21/19",
        value: "110000"
    }]
}
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried. SO isn't a free code writing service. Objective here is to help you fix your own attempts when they aren't working properly...not to do all the work for you

Answer (score 0):

You just need to recursively navigate that object with your selectors while grabbing the elements from the page once you get to one of the leaves, which you can tell because those are of type `string`.

To do so, you could use [`https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [`Document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector):

```js
const startingJson = {
  address:"tbody > tr > td:nth-of-type(4) > p",
  bar: '#baz',
  comps: [{
    address: "tbody > tr:nth-of-type(1) > td:nth-of-type(1) > p",
    link: "tbody > tr:nth-of-type(1) > td:nth-of-type(1) > p > a",
    dateLastSold: "tbody > tr:nth-of-type(1) > td:nth-of-type(2) > p",
    value: "tbody > tr:nth-of-type(1) > td:nth-of-type(3) > p",
    qux: '#qux',
  }, {
    address: "tbody > tr:nth-of-type(2) > td:nth-of-type(1) > p",
    link: "tbody > tr:nth-of-type(2) > td:nth-of-type(1) > p > a",
    dateLastSold: "tbody > tr:nth-of-type(2) > td:nth-of-type(2) > p",
    value: "tbody > tr:nth-of-type(2) > td:nth-of-type(3) > p"
  }],
  list: [
    '.foo p',
    '.bar span',
  ],
};

function getElements(selectors) {
  if (typeof selectors === 'string') {
    // If `selectors` is a string, that's a selector we can use to grab an
    // element from the page. You might want to use document.querySelectorAll
    // instead, in case more than one element is returned, and handle that
    // appropriately:
    const element = document.querySelector(selectors);
    
    // Extract the `textContent` from that element, if any:
    return element ? (element.textContent || '') : null;
  }
  
  if (Array.isArray(selectors)) {
    // If we are passed an array, we need to recursively explore all the children
    // while filling in an array of the same size that we are going to return:
    return selectors.map(selector => getElements(selector));
  }
  
  if (typeof selectors === 'object') {
    // Lastly, if we are passed an object, we need to explore all its entries
    // and return an object with the same keys but with the values resolved using
    // this same function recursively:
    return Object.entries(selectors).reduce((elements, [key, value]) => {
      elements[key] = getElements(value);
      
      return elements;
    }, {}); 
  }
  
  return null;
}

console.log(getElements(startingJson));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="foo"><p>Foo<p></div>
<div class="bar"><span>Bar</span></div>
<div id="baz">Baz</div>
<div id="qux">Qux</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a generic traversal function using lodash's `_.transform()`, which handles both objects, and arrays. When calling traverse on your object, pass a function (`fn`) to handle the non object values.

In this case, you can use `Document.querySelector()` on the values, and then extract the text content from the nodes.

```js
const recursiveTransform = (fn, val) => _.transform(val, (acc, v, key) => {  
  acc[key] = _.isObject(v) ? recursiveTransform(fn, v) : fn(v);
});

const startingJson = {"address":"tbody > tr > td:nth-of-type(4) > p","bar":"#baz","comps":[{"address":"tbody > tr:nth-of-type(1) > td:nth-of-type(1) > p","link":"tbody > tr:nth-of-type(1) > td:nth-of-type(1) > p > a","dateLastSold":"tbody > tr:nth-of-type(1) > td:nth-of-type(2) > p","value":"tbody > tr:nth-of-type(1) > td:nth-of-type(3) > p","qux":"#qux"},{"address":"tbody > tr:nth-of-type(2) > td:nth-of-type(1) > p","link":"tbody > tr:nth-of-type(2) > td:nth-of-type(1) > p > a","dateLastSold":"tbody > tr:nth-of-type(2) > td:nth-of-type(2) > p","value":"tbody > tr:nth-of-type(2) > td:nth-of-type(3) > p"}],"list":[".foo p",".bar span"]};

const result = recursiveTransform(q => {
  const r = document.querySelector(q);

  return r && r.textContent;
}, startingJson);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
<div class="foo"><p>Foo<p></div>
<div class="bar"><span>Bar</span></div>
<div id="baz">Baz</div>
<div id="qux">Qux</div>
```